# In App Purchase Error Message Google Play Console

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play-console

When I upload my in app purchases csv to google play console I receive an error message (in german):

[image: error message in google play console]

The german text says

> you can upload maximum -1 In App purchases per App.

Does it mean I overcome the limit of In-App purchases? If so how do other e.g. Newspaper apps do it when they release every day a product which should have a unique purchase ID?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the Play Console when rendering the number of maximum in-app purchases.

The actual maximum number is 1000. You can't have more than 1000 in-app purchases per app.